# bring data to new view through UITableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, uitableview, xcode4

I want to populate a `UITableView` with data from a database and, when tap a cell, in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, sending selected cell to a new View. I accomplished it with the standard way. Now I also want that when the cell is tapped, the data of the cell is also brought to the other view. I am doing like this but its not working

`MyCoreDataClassName *object = [fetchedObjecs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`

This is the same way I read on other forum posts but its not helpfull for me. Whenever I use this line and run my app, when I tap the cell its hangs for a second and exits the app. What I am doing wrong? Kindly guide me.

P.S: I am using core data to fill in the Table.

Regards.

Comment: you can ask me anything what you want to know more ?

Comment: Lol. With this statement `I also want that when the cell is tapped, the data of the cell is also brought to the other view` what exactly are you trying to accomplish ?

Comment: Its simple, I just want the data on the selected cell to be brought forward on the other view. For example I have 3 columns in my Core Data, from which the UITableView is populated. I want that when UITableViewCell is tapped, the data in that particular cell is available to me on the other view.

Comment: Ok. So if you click the label on the third row (which is the third item on your tableview), it needs to appear in the next view ? Do you want it to appear on the navigation bar ? Or again in a table ? or in what format??

Comment: I did that work already. I navigated it to another screen which has a textbox and a save button. I just want my data to be in my hands of the selected row.

Comment: @Wasim let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1062/discussion-between-legolas-and-wasim)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your objective is to just pass the data FId from your view to the next view. You can do this in many ways. Let me post just one way - using `NSUserDefaults`

Consider this example code.

IN THE FIRST VIEW:

```
NSInteger row = [indexPath row];

NSUserDefaults *rowSelect = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];


if (row ==0){
    [rowSelect setInteger:0 forKey:@"theChosenRow"];

}
if (row ==1){
    [rowSelect setInteger:1 forKey:@"theChosenRow"];

}
if (row ==2){
    [rowSelect setInteger:2 forKey:@"theChosenRow"];

}
if (row ==3){
    [rowSelect setInteger:3 forKey:@"theChosenRow"];

}
if (row ==4){
    [rowSelect setInteger:4 forKey:@"theChosenRow"];

}

// In general you can set  [rowSelect setInteger:row forKey:@"theChosenRow"];
```

IN THE NEXT VIEW:

```
    NSUserDefaults *rowSelect = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSInteger rowInfo = [rowSelect integerForKey:@"theChosenRow"];


   if (rowInfo == 10) //for example
        // Fetch Data for 10th row and Display contents for your tenth row.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer. Let me check it, I will get back to you shortly :)

Comment: np. Please be clear in your question. You would have gotten an answer in 5 minutes :D anyways. ! GLuck !